# jQuery post() apostrophe how is apostrophe automatically converted to html numeric entity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, html-entities

I am posting some data to the server using JQuery.post(), as shown below.  When I receive the post data on the server side, I am surprised to see that the post variables already have single apostrophes converted to html numbers (ie. ' is replaced with `&#39;`).  How is this happening?  Does the conversion happen in Jquery.post()?  I cannot find any documentation on this.

```
$("#save").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var postdata = "id="+id+"&note="+$("#note").val();

    $.post("save_note.php", postdata, function(data){
    $('#save_status').text(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: not sure why, but htmlspecialchars_decode() will fix it

Comment: or may be in the save_note.php you can echo the data by htmlspecialchars_decode() ing it...

Comment: yes, I know I can decode the special chars. I am just wondering where the conversion is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening in the web browser.

Check the value of `$("#note").val()` - remember under the covers when you type something in a form field it's being inserted into the HTML DOM.

Comment: However, the value is not HTML encoded when it's in the DOM element. The element is an object, it's not HTML code once it has been parsed from the source. The value has to be specifically encoded at some point.

Comment: How do you know it's not encoded? Anything you use to pull it out will automatically decode it for display.

Comment: Well, I haven't read the source code of browsers, so I can't be absolutely certain, but that would be a pretty stupid design, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't happen at all.

The likely reason is that the value is already HTML encoded before you read it and put it in the postdata string.

Comment: That makes sense.  Does JQuery val() automatically html encode strings?  It's not clear in the documentation.

Comment: @Civil777: No, it doesn't. It's likely that it's encoded already when in the element, i.e. encoded at some earlier stage.

Answer (score 0):

You sould either :

- [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
- jquery's way (at least one of) [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method on form, like this :

  ```
  $("#save").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(event.target).closest('form');
    //var postdata = "id="+id+"&note="+$("#note").val();

    $.post($form.attr('method'), $form.serialize(), function(data){
    $('#save_status').text(data);
    });
  });
  ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: useful information, but it does not really answer my questions.

Comment: try with the jquery's way and you won't have the encoding problem.